# How to validate the password of a user without using shadow.h in linux in C(++)

Tags: c++, c, linux, authentication, passwords

I have a project in C++ (https://ari-web.xyz/gh/kos) and
it's like sudo but in C++ and doesn't use PAM, I want it
to keep it this way but is there a way to validate the
password of a user without using shadow.h? some people also
don't have /etc/shadow for security reasons so...

Is there another way to do it?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can parse `/etc/shadow` yourself if you want, but why do that if you have library functions for it?

Comment: @user17732522 I'm not sure, some guy a bit ago told me they're using something else for the auth and they have no shadow, I forgot what is it but appreantly it's more secure

Comment: @user17732522 True, but is there any other alternative besides PAM?

Comment: OK, yes, that may be, but then you will need to add support for that authentification method to your tool. Usually PAM abstracts that all away, but if you don't want to use it you need to implement support for each method yourself.

Comment: @user17732522 Damn, so basically I am stuck with `shadow.h`?

Comment: I would also caution that implementing something like sudo correctly is tricky. Even sudo itself had many security bugs allowing for privilege escalation. You need to know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @user17732522 :shrug: will see in the future, so far nothing is wrong

Comment: Why exactly do you not want to use `shadow.h`? If you are using e.g. glibc then it even supports other methods than a local `/etc/shadow` file via NSS.

Comment: Generally speaking, rolling a custom alternative to long established system interfaces is among the least secure approaches available.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Indeed but not like it's some industrial thing so I don't mind

Comment: @user17732522 Not sure tbh, but thanks for the NSS tip :)

Comment: @user17732522 Leave the NSS thing as an answer and I'll mark it as the solution, I might use that

Comment: @Ari157, I was talking about trying to find an alternative to `shadow.h`.  But indeed, if you're not concerned with security then what is the point of this question, or of the utility you are trying to write overall?